# pickle is not installing in windows

Tags: python, windows, pickle

I wanted to build a chatbot using python. So I get help from this URL https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-chatbot-project/.It it I am getting two errors, first, that wheel is not getting install and second error while installing! I really wanted to build this chatbot and also I am a beginner in this! So please help me! Thank you in advance!

```
(chatbot) C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\Downloads\CHATBOT\make-3.81-src>pip install pickle5
Collecting pickle5
  Using cached pickle5-0.0.11.tar.gz (132 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pickle5
  Building wheel for pickle5 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-456wvzqt'
       cwd: C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\pickle5\
  Complete output (36 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
  copying pickle5\pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
  copying pickle5\pickletools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
  copying pickle5\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
  copying pickle5\test\pickletester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
  copying pickle5\test\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
  copying pickle5\test\test_picklebuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
  copying pickle5\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
  running build_ext
  building 'pickle5._pickle' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpickle5/_pickle.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/_pickle.obj
  _pickle.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpickle5/picklebufobject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/picklebufobject.obj
  picklebufobject.c
  pickle5/picklebufobject.c(20): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_FromObject': inconsistent dll linkage
  C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(18): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_FromObject'
  pickle5/picklebufobject.c(39): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer': inconsistent dll linkage
  C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(22): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer'
  pickle5/picklebufobject.c(58): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_Release': inconsistent dll linkage
  C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(24): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_Release'
  pickle5/picklebufobject.c(208): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_Type': inconsistent dll linkage
  C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(13): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_Type'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__pickle build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/_pickle.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/picklebufobject.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.lib
  python38.lib(python38.dll) : error LNK2005: PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer already defined in picklebufobject.obj
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.exp
  build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1169
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pickle5
  Running setup.py clean for pickle5
Failed to build pickle5
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for pickle5 which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: pickle5
    Running setup.py install for pickle5 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kd65tyg1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\Include\pickle5'
         cwd: C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\pickle5\
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
    copying pickle5\pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
    copying pickle5\pickletools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
    copying pickle5\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
    copying pickle5\test\pickletester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
    copying pickle5\test\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
    copying pickle5\test\test_picklebuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
    copying pickle5\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\test
    running build_ext
    building 'pickle5._pickle' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpickle5/_pickle.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/_pickle.obj
    _pickle.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpickle5/picklebufobject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/picklebufobject.obj
    picklebufobject.c
    pickle5/picklebufobject.c(20): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_FromObject': inconsistent dll linkage
    C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(18): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_FromObject'
    pickle5/picklebufobject.c(39): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer': inconsistent dll linkage
    C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(22): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer'
    pickle5/picklebufobject.c(58): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_Release': inconsistent dll linkage
    C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(24): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_Release'
    pickle5/picklebufobject.c(208): warning C4273: 'PyPickleBuffer_Type': inconsistent dll linkage
    C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\include\picklebufobject.h(13): note: see previous definition of 'PyPickleBuffer_Type'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__pickle build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/_pickle.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5/picklebufobject.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.lib
    python38.lib(python38.dll) : error LNK2005: PyPickleBuffer_GetBuffer already defined in picklebufobject.obj
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.exp
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pickle5\_pickle.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1169
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sakshi Pathak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6v_0wp4n\\pickle5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kd65tyg1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Sakshi Pathak\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\Include\pickle5' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

you might try `pip install --no-binary pickle5`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the one error is coming, `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using conda package installer Try this
worked for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pickle5
```

[conda documentation](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pickle5)